# @FindBy search for element that has sub element which meets condition

Tags: java, selenium

Lets say i've got this html:

```
<table class="list">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="amazon">
            <td>
                <p> 10 Euros <p>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="otherRetaile">
            <td>
                <p> 10 Euros <p>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="otherRetailer1">
            <td>        
                <p> 11 Euros <p>
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <a href="otherRetailer2">
            <td>
                <p> 12 Euros <p>
```

and now i want to access the <p> that is in the same tr as the <a> tag with the href "amazon". What's the best approach to this, do i need a for loop over all those div's or can i use the @FindBy annotation? Do i need multiple @FindBy or a @FindAll to get all the divs in my list to check those for amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xpath with `/..` like that:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href,'amazon')]/../../td/p[1]
```

`/..` alows you to reach parent of the current element

or shorter version

```
//td/a[contains(@href,'amazon')]/../..//p[1]
```

Comment: @test123123132 please accept the answer by clicking checkmark under arrow if that answer helped you

Comment: Am going to. Just have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

almost the similar as @Lia answer, but a little different in searching element

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='amazon']"));
parent = element.findElement(By.xpath("./../../p"));

Comment: Already tried Lia's answer and it worked. Hers is with the annotation which fits my code better. Thanks anyways :)